# how to keep 'index' param when call url helper in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-route

When I tried to call `url` helper in a view file like below:

```
$url = $this->url();
```

The result is if:

1. At current the controller is `index` and action is `index`. With index is default action key, it will be only out:
   `[base_url]\[module]`
2. At current the controller is not `index` and action is no t`index` it will only out:
   `[base_url]\[module]\[controller]\action`

But I want the link in 1st case is:

```
[base_url]\[module]\index\index
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a param to url helper you will retrive a full url for 1st case.

For example:

in index.phtml

```
<?php
 echo $this->url(array('test'=>'test'));
?>
```

It will print out:

```
/[root]/public/[module]/[controller]/index/test/test
```

The you can get index action, and you've just ignore the `/test/test`

```
<?php
 $url  = $this->url(array('test'=>'test'));
 echo substr($url,0,-10);
?>
```

Output:

```
/[folder]/public/[module]/[controller]/index
```

Comment: Having to use an additional parameter sucks though :/